# saving captured image to server(web application in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am taking a snapshot of stream and displaying it as a canvas.
How can I save the captured snapshot to file on my server?
Ps: The below code is part of a jsp page and the project is hosted on server(tomcat). I don't want to save it on user system, just on the server hosting project.

```
<canvas id="snapshot" width=130 height=130 align="right"></canvas>
<video id="player" width="220" height="140" align="right"; controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>

<script>
    var player = document.getElementById('player'); 
    var snapshotCanvas = document.getElementById('snapshot');
    var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
    var videoTracks;
    var handleSuccess = function(stream) {

        // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.

        player.srcObject = stream;
        videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
        };

        captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var context = snapshot.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(player, 150, 150,320,240,0,0, snapshotCanvas.width, snapshotCanvas.height);
        var imgdata = snapshot.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newdata = imgdata.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-stream');
    });

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(handleSuccess);

    // Stop all video streams.
    videoTracks.forEach(function(track) {track.stop()});
</script>
```